# uploading files to server using AS3 and PHP error

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file to a server using AS3 and PHP. Here is my AS3 Code and then the PHP code. The folder I am trying to upload to is writable. and the file size is about 20Kb. The php script is on my server, and the flash file calls it.

```
var UPLOAD_URL: String ="linktophpscriptonMysite"
var fr: FileReference;
var request: URLRequest = new URLRequest();
request.url = UPLOAD_URL;

function startThis(): void {

     fr = new FileReference();
     fr.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
     fr.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
     fr.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
     fr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
     fr.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
     startUpload()
}

function startUpload(): void {
    try {
        var success: Boolean = fr.browse();
        trace("success")
    } catch (error: Error) {
        trace("Unable to browse for files.", Error);
    }
}

function progressHandler(event: ProgressEvent): void {
    trace(event.bytesLoaded, event.bytesTotal);

}
function ioErrorHandler(event: IOErrorEvent): void {
    //trace("Some error ", event.target.data.systemResult);
    //systemResult is echoed by PHP

}
function openHandler(event: Event): void {
    try {
        //var success: Boolean = fr.browse();
    } catch (error: Error) {
        trace("Unable to browse for files.", Error);
    }

}
function completeHandler(event: Event): void {
    trace(event.target.data.systemResult);
//this reads the result, again, from PHP echo "systemResult=all is good";


}

function selectHandler(event: Event): void {

    fr.upload(request);
}
```

And then, here is the php code: This code is a general upload script I found on the php manual site

```
   <?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

try {


    // Undefined | Multiple Files | $_FILES Corruption Attack
    // If this request falls under any of them, treat it invalid.
    if (
        !isset($_FILES['upfile']['error']) ||
        is_array($_FILES['upfile']['error'])
    ) {
         echo "systemResult=Error";
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');

    }

    // Check $_FILES['upfile']['error'] value.
    switch ($_FILES['upfile']['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');

        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
    }

    // You should also check filesize here. max is 100 mb
    if ($_FILES['upfile']['size'] > 10000000) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
    }

    // DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['upfile']['mime'] VALUE !!
    // Check MIME Type by yourself.
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    if (false === $ext = array_search(
        $finfo->file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']),
        array(
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'png' => 'image/png',
            'gif' => 'image/gif',
        ),
        true
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
    }

    // You should name it uniquely.
    // DO NOT USE $_FILES['upfile']['name'] WITHOUT ANY VALIDATION !!
    // On this example, obtain safe unique name from its binary data.
    if (!move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'],
        sprintf('./uploads/%s.%s',
            sha1_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']),
            $ext
        )
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
    }

    echo 'File is uploaded successfully.';

} catch (RuntimeException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}

?>
```

The problem I am having is that the file does not get uploaded, and I dont get any feedback from php as to why.

Thank you for any help

UPDATE:
Thank you @akmozo for the reply and answer. Like I said in my comment, this script worked

```
<?php

 $uploads_dir = './uploads/';

  if( $_FILES['Filedata']['error'] == 0 ){

  if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'],     $uploads_dir.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'] ) ){

     echo 'ok';
     echo 'systemResult=Awesome';

     exit();

     }

   }

   echo 'error';
   echo 'systemResult=did not work';

   exit();

   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the upload data field name of a `FileReference` object is **`"Filedata"`** and that's what you should use in your PHP code ( `$_FILES['Filedata']` ...).

You can of course change that name in the [`FileReference.upload()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#upload()) function :

```
 fr.upload(request, 'upfile');
```

Hope that can help

Comment: thank you for your quick comment, and answer. Unfortunately, I still get the same error, and nothing gets uploaded. I tried both changing the  upfile to filedata, without luck. However, this basic script php script worked, which tells me that flash is doing what is supposed to do, but maybe the php script has issues in it

Comment: @FlashV8 Sorry, but I don't see what's the problem exactly : Flash or PHP ?